Синонимизировать метки на тему [автозагрузка]
Предлагаю синонимизировать метки

autoload (41 вопрос) нет описания
автозагрузка (47 вопросов) нет описания

Основная - автозагрузка, т. к. она на русском.

В целом, autoload это название функции в PHP, оно не подлежит переводу, большинство вопросов именно про PHP. А вот "автозагрузка" может означать вообще что угодно.

@aepot Да вопрос спорный. Но что-то точно надо синонимизировать.

Автозагрузка - это autorun, а autoload - это что-то другое.

autorun это автозапуск :) говоря языком винды, автозагрузка это startup apps. В общем, понятно что ничего непонятно.

@aepot, хм, да, по идее автозапуск может относиться к флешке или dvd, например. Хотя, в современных реалиях в большинстве случаев автозапуск - синоним автозагрузки.
